# Angular custom library npm install gives Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

Tags: angular, npm, npm-install, angular-module, angular-library

I've made a custom angular module library and after using it in my main app the library doesn't work and this is the warning that shows up

`Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression`

Here's how I'm importing the library

`import { MyLibraryModule } from 'my-lib'`

in `package.json`

```
"library": "file:../dist/UI-library"
```

Currently I'm installing the from a local directory where the dist files of build library are built.

Answer (score 1):

In your library go to the dist/library folder and run `npm pack`
This will create a `.tgz` file of your lib. Then in your package.json file install the library from this packaged `.tgz` file. Like:

```
 "library": "file:./library.tgz"
```

When you publish to npm this is what npm does and that's what you install when you run an `npm install` a `.tgz` packaged file.